# Using 'self' in an @implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, trigger.io

I'm trying to play voice audio **on top of** the `iPodMusicPlayer` by making a TriggerIO native plugin, however I'm having trouble accessing the `self` object.

```
#import "alert_API.h"

@implementation alert_API

+ (void)play:(ForgeTask*)task text:(NSString *)filename {
    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Rondo_Alla_Turka_Short" withExtension:@"aiff"];
    NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
    NSError* error = nil;


    /* ERROR: /Users/gsquare567/forge-workspace/plugins/audio/inspector/ios-inspector/ForgeModule/alert/alert_API.m:45:13: Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'? */
    self->player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    /* ERROR: /Users/gsquare567/forge-workspace/plugins/audio/inspector/ios-inspector/ForgeModule/alert/alert_API.m:45:13: Incomplete definition of type 'struct objc_class' */
    if(!self.player)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
    }


    [task success:nil];
}

@end
```

The property is defined in `alert_API.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface alert_API : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer* player;
+ (void)play:(ForgeTask*)task text:(NSString *)filename;

@end
```

What do I need to do here to be able to access the `player` property throughout my API?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a class method, not an instance method. In a class method, `self` refers to the `class`, not any instance. You can't access ivars from a class method. In a class method, `self` can be used to call other class methods, but that's basically it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `play:text:` method is static, meaning `self` doesn't refer to an instance with the property, but to the class object for `alert_API`. You can either change your method to be an instance method (`- (void)` instead of `+ (void)`):

```
- (void)play:(ForgeTask*)task text:(NSString *)filename;
```

Or if you want to keep the method static, you will have to implement a static method which returns a player singleton:

```
+ (AVAudioPlayer *)playerInstance;
```

Then use `[alert_API playerInstance]` to access the player from your methods.

Comment: The `+` means class method, not static method.

Comment: @rmaddy +1 also `self is not valid in that context.` It is valid. It's a reference to the class object rather than an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `-` instance method compiles, but to work as a plugin method I need to keep it as a class method. I just learned a lot :)

Comment: @rmaddy Just out of curiosity: Can you please provide an example *static method* which can't be called *class method*

Comment: @Viral - Objective-C doesn't have static methods. You can define static functions in a source file but these aren't methods.