# How to initialize Objective C class variable in init?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constructor

In the `@interface`, I have this declaration:

```
@interface myClass {
   NSDictionary * myData;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDictionary * data;
+ (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;

@end
```

In the `@implementation`, I have this code:

```
@implementation

@synthesize data;

+ (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)freshData {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self->data = freshData;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

But I got error `Incomplete definition of type 'struct objc_class` on `self->data`.

If I change it into `self.data`, I got error `Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?`

If I remove the `self`, I got error `Instance variable 'data' accessed in class method.'

But if I change the method type from `+` (class method) to `-` (instance method), I cannot access the init.

And I cannot fix this error by change the assignment from `data` to `myData` either.

How should I make a constructor?

The link that I have learned from (but not helping) are:

- [Using 'self' in an @implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951441/using-self-in-an-implementation)
- http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this also

```
+ (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)freshData {
    return [[self alloc]initWithData:freshData];
}
- (instancetype) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)freshData {

    NSParameterAssert(freshData != nil);

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.data = freshData;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: If I only implement `- (instancetype) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)freshData` without `+ (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)freshData`, what's the downside?

Comment: Well you can do that also, if there is not any issue with creating the object ofthat class, as with instance method you need to create the object of that class to use that method and with class method you can call that method with Class.

Comment: Check this also for class method vs instance method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-instance-methods

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would not expect an `init*` method to be a class method. Generally you have a class method with a name like `default*`, `shared*`, or `*withDictionary:`. So for a class named `myClass`, I'd expect to see this:

```
+ (myClass*)myClassWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    return [[myClass alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
}
```

This can be important when the static analyzer analyses your code, for example. Naming is significant in Objective-C and hints the compiler (and analyzer) as to what the code's intent is.

Comment: You mean like `[UIColor colorWithCGColor:]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what's wrong that I can't access instance init method constructor... I forgot to do `alloc` first before `init`. That's why I only can access the `init` method if I changed the `init` into class constructor, because I immediately wrote `[MyClass initWithData:]`. I'm so used to  Swift simplicity that when I have to go back to Objective C, I kinda forget about the drill... Then your answer reminds me why the `init` must be instance method, not class method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not using public init method (+)

```
+ (id) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

Change to

```
- (instancetype) initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

And I highly recommend you to use `instancetype` instead of `id` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972221/would-it-be-beneficial-to-begin-using-instancetype-instead-of-id)
)